# Resteasy ExceptionMapper returning no result

Tags: java, rest, resteasy

I am developing a REST-facade for an EJB service, which means it calls the EJB, translates the result to representations a REST-caller will understand and then returns it (as json or xml). All of that works splendid. But the EJB service throws a variety of exceptions, e. g. when no result is found or a few different other cases. Since I don't want those propagating to the REST-caller, I implemented an ExceptionMapper:

```
public class EjbExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<EJBException> {

    private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EjbExceptionMapper.class);

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(final EJBException exception) {
        ResponseBuilder result = Response.status(Status.BAD_REQUEST);
        logger.debug("Bad request:", exception);
        if (exception.getCause() != null) {
            final Throwable cause = exception.getCause();
            if (cause instanceof NoDeliveryFoundException) {
                logger.debug("Found NoDeliveryFoundException:", cause);
                result = Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).entity(cause.getMessage());
            }
        }
        return result.build();
    }
}
```

All the exceptions from my EJB-service arrive as `javax.ejb.EJBException`, which this Mapper manages to catch just fine, with different custom Exceptions of the application as causes. The plan is to return different Responses depending on the type of cause of the EJBException. The logger-calls used for debugging are both executed in case I get a NoDeliveryFoundException as the cause, so I know it's executed (the Mapper registered correctly and is used for mapping), but the client never sees a response.

Every call leading to an EJBException in the underlying service (and thus the use of this ExceptionMapper) leads to no Response at all, as if the toResponse()-method were returning null and not a custom built Response.

I even went so far as to log the Response right before returning it, it exists and contains what I expect, so I am positive that it is returned by the toResponse-method. But still, my client receives no Response.

So now I'm stumped and since no search managed to even find someone describing a similar problem, I turn to you, dear SO. ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `toResponse`-method contains some conflicting logic.

`Response.status(Status.NO_CONTENT).entity(cause.getMessage());`

Here you are assigning the the HTTP status code `204 No Content`, but you are also adding a response. You can't set the status to `204 No Content` and return a response body at the same time.

Also, if `Exception#getCause()` is null or if it's *not* an instance of `NoDeliveryFoundException`, the response body is empty.

Could this be the cause of your problems?

Comment: Probably not, since my problem isn't that I get a response with empty entity or something similar. I get no response at all, the client doesn't even get the HTTP status code. An empty response body would be fine by me, so long as I at least get the code to the client.

Comment: And which client are you using? If you use `curl` with the `--verbose`-flag, what do you get back?

Comment: I used either a browser directly or the simple REST client for Opera. Will have to check with curl once I'm back in the office. I'm not actually at work on sundays. ;)

Comment: cURL says it does receive a response with status 204. Interesting that any browser-based requests would show nothing at all, but as long as a Response exists and contains a status, I'm ok with that. The client to be built will be a java application anyway.

Comment: That's because you return a "204 No Content", which implies that the response does not contain a body. Please don't build you application so that it violates the HTTP spec. Quote from the spec: "The 204 response MUST NOT include a message-body, and thus is always terminated by the first empty line after the header fields."

Comment: Yes, thanks. :) My main problem was that calls with a browser said they got no response at all, not even the return code. My initial plan was to use the enity to transport detail-information over why the call failed, but since that violates the spec, I'll put it in a custom header instead.